# Jquery delegate with a dom instead of selector

Tags: jquery

I used to use .on as below:

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
=> 
$div=$('<div />');
$div.on('click',fn(){...});
```

but for delegate we have :

```
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
```

and

```
$div.delegate...
```

does not work!.
In this case i have no selector, just the Dom. what should i do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: currently using JQuery 2.1.3 , does it matter?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method.

Comment: Basically what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: actually i use delegate to add events to elements that future will be added in the document,

Comment: can i do it with .on ?

Comment: Yes. See Wolff's answer.

Answer (score 2):

`selector` can only be a string. To use a DOM element or jq matched set, you could filter it inside handler, e.g:

```
$( document).on( "click", null, data, handler );

//later
var $div=$('<div />');

function handler(event){
   if($(event.target).closest($div).length)
     //do some stuff
}
```

```js
$(document).on("click", null, {
  data: "some data"
}, handler);

//later
var $div = $('<div />').html('the DIV to call handler');
$div.appendTo('body');

function handler(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest($div).length) {
    //do some stuff   
    alert('handler call for the DIV');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  other div, no click event bound
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked , but $(this) inside the handler function does not work.

Comment: $( document).on(options.openerEvent , function(){
 th=$(this);
 if($(event.target).closest(options.openerSelector).length)
 
 {
 
 //activeSelector=th;loadFiles(options.homePath);
 
 }
 });

Comment: actually this reffers to document

Comment: But you can just reset context using call() for example.

Comment: if the event is click, how can i get clicked element? because i have multiple   selectors. thanks