# Is there a shortcut version of placing multiple children elements in a delegated event selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-selectors

Consider the following table within a container div:

```
        <div id="container">
            <table id="longTableIdentifier">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="one"/></td>
                        <td><input class="two"/></td>
                        <td><input class="three"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I want to bind a handler for listening to change events for some of the inputs (e.g. class one and three) within the table. Currently my code looks like that and is working:

```
    $('#container').on('change','#longTableIdentifier .one, #longTableIdentifier .three', function() {
        // do stuff
    });
```

But I am wondering if there is a shortcut for this statement which allows to specify the same handler without having to write the (possibly long) id of the table over and over again (especially when considering five or more target elements). It is crucial for the handlers to be attached to the container-div and not to a child of it to guarantee the execution order of the events so putting the id at the beginning after the container-div is not an option.

I know this can also be accomplished by simply defining classes for the desired elements but if possible I would like to spare that and keep the html clean instead.

I was thinking about something like

```
    $('#container').on('change','#longTableIdentifier (.one OR .three'), function() {
        // do stuff
    });
```

but I couldn't find a way to accomplish that yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you have `.one`/`.three` elsewhere, then `$('#container').on('change','.one,.three',` would do what you want

Comment: The selector must be a string, so can't (eg) be a jquery collection.  Instead you could filter *inside* the function, basic example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35551193/2181514  `$('#container').on('change', '#longTableIdentifier', function() { if (!$(this).filter(".one,.three").length == 0)  return });`

Comment: Ok so I guess there is just no way of accomplishing what I thought of. I used ur proposed approach to handle it.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it directly, if you have a lot of different inputs that you can't give a common class, you could possibly generate the selector, eg `var inps = ['.one','.three']; var sel = inps.map(s=> "#longTableIdentifier " + s).join(","); console.log(sel)`